# Find a String occurrence between Two occurrences of other

Tags: string, perl, shell, search, scripting

I've a very long file as follows.

Input file :-

```
Text Point
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
String
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Text Point
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Text Point
String
Blah
Blah
Text Point
Blah
Blah
Blah
String
Blah
Blah
Blah
Text Point
Blah
Blah
String
Blah
```

After each Occurrence of a 'Text Point', and before the next occurrence, I expect 'String' to occur at maximum once. I've to extract string if it is occurring between Two consecutive 'Text point's to a output file Or I've to put a dash if it is not occurring.

In this case, I need a output like this

```
String
-
String
String
String
```

I tried using following command

```
sed -n '/Text point/{:a;N;/^\n/s/^\n//;/Text point/{p;s/.*//;};ba};' $1 | grep "String" >> Outfile
```

But the problem with this is when string isn't found it will not append anything to outfile.
So please help me out with the code. Thanks.

Comment: paste some code that u have tried?

Comment: sed -n '/Text point/{:a;N;/^\n/s/^\n//;/Text point/{p;s/.*//;};ba};' $1 | grep "String" >> Outfile , But the problem with this is when string isn't found it will not append anything to outfile.

Comment: dont put code in comment put code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/^Text Point/{print p; p="-" } /String/{ p=$0} END{print p}'  input
```

Comment: Tried but it's giving only half the output :-(

Comment: Your description of the problem is ambiguous, and I interpreted it to be more difficult than it actually is.  Solution modified to match what I believe you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution with *perl*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/="Text Point";

while(<>) {

    if(/String/m) {
        print "String \n" ;
    }
    else{
        print "- \n"    ;   
    }
}
```

Comment: /m only affects what `^` or `$` match so is useless there; did you mean `/^String$/m` ?

Comment: This method will print an extra `-` because it treats the empty string before the first `"Text Point"` as a line.  To fix, you can change the body of your while loop to just `print /String/ ? "String\n" : "-\n" if $. > 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print /(.*String.*\n)/ ? $1 : "-\n" for split /(?=Text Point)/' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-0777`: Slurp entire file
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.